# PG ADMIN aquires a lock on a table on execution of a select query

Tags: postgresql, locking, pgadmin

A select query was run on a table using PGAdmin and then after few hours we see that the application doesn't respond to any request to be processed.
Found a lock attained on the same table the select query was executed when checked the db.
we had to kill the lock to bring the application back to active state.

Has anyone encountered such similar issues?  Any suggestions and help please.

Comment: if multiple people are working with same postgres instance it might happen that some daemon/dangling process can be created and we need to manually kill it or restart the services to resume operations on db

Comment: Every SELECT query will acquire a lock on table, usually `ACCESS SHARE`. So what kind of lock was it, what query was being executed and what got blocked?